# Visitor array has empty values with Smart Map plugin (using MaxMind)

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I'm receiving an array with empty values when trying to get visitor info using the [Smart Map plugin](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/) and its [Visitor Geolocation](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/visitor-geolocation/) feature. I'm using MaxMind's free trial ($5 worth of queries) since FreeGeoIp.net is not recommended and I've double checked the plugin settings and cleared all caches. Looking at the MaxMind account there are no queries logged and my map/debug output has empty location values via PHP ([screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wd8irryxs1qpv7q/Screenshot%202018-03-13%2020.35.09.png?dl=0)). Working locally on a .dev domain, running Craft 3 RC and tried FreeGeoIp.net as well but to no avail.

Twig:

```
{% set visitor = craft.smartMap.visitor %}
{% if visitor %}
  <pre>{{ dump(visitor) }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

Output:

```
 array(8) {
  ["ip"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["city"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["state"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["zipcode"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["country"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["latitude"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["longitude"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["coords"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Could this be part of my problem? `craft.app.request.userIP` is returning `string(3) "::1"`. A PHP config issue? Using MAMP Pro on macOS FWIW.

Comment: Good theory... Oddly, I just did some testing locally, and wasn't able to reproduce the problem. Hit me up on Slack via DM, and we can troubleshoot it together.

Comment: Thanks for connecting on Slack Lindsey! I'll be sure to post an answer here when we get to the bottom of it. Great plugin support.  : )

Answer (score 2):

Was using the MaxMind free trial and I didn't have the Web Service set correctly in the Smart Map plugin settings. It needed to be set to GeoIP2 City.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! To be clear (for future readers), it needed to be set to "GeoIP2 City" because that was the package that you paid for. The dropdown needs to match your selected MaxMind subscription package.